# Subscribing lambda to SNS using boto3. Lambda trigger is not set

Tags: aws-lambda, triggers, boto3, publish-subscribe, amazon-sns

I have created script that creates SNS topic and subscribe already created lambda to it. Everything works fine, except that Lambda trigger is not set to SNS topic.
If I try to publish message to the topic I get in a CloudWatch Logs message with this information:

```
{\"ErrorCode\":\"AccessDeniedException\",\"ErrorMessage\":\"User: sns.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction on resource: arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:<my_account_id_here>:function:sns-test-lambda because no resource-based policy allows the lambda:InvokeFunction action\",\"lambdaRequestId\":\"Unrecoverable\"}
```

If the problem is that: *sns.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction*, how can I set policy to SNS that allows to invoke lambda function?

I tried to create topic programatically without subscribing and then subscribe using AWS console and it worked- lambda was a subscriber on SNS topic panel and SNS topic was indicated in Lambda triggers panel, which is what I'm looking for to achieve (but programatically). When I publish a message in that scenario everyting works fine, lambda is executing, CloudWatch Logs appears with succesful status.

Python script:

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='xxx')


class SnsWrapper:
    """Encapsulates Amazon SNS topic and subscription functions."""

    def __init__(self, sns_resource):
        """
        :param sns_resource: A Boto3 Amazon SNS resource.
        """
        self.sns_resource = sns_resource

    def create_topic(self, name, attributes=None):
        """
        Creates a notification topic.

        :param name: The name of the topic to create.
        :param attributes: Attributes of topic.
        :return: The newly created topic.
        """
        try:
            if attributes:
                topic = self.sns_resource.create_topic(Name=name, Attributes=attributes)
            else:
                topic = self.sns_resource.create_topic(Name=name)
            logger.info("Created topic %s with ARN %s.", name, topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't create topic %s.", name)
            raise
        else:
            return topic

    def list_topics(self):
        """
        Lists topics for the current account.

        :return: An iterator that yields the topics.
        """
        try:
            topics_iter = self.sns_resource.topics.all()
            logger.info("Got topics.")
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get topics.")
            raise
        else:
            return topics_iter

    @staticmethod
    def delete_topic(topic):
        """
        Deletes a topic. All subscriptions to the topic are also deleted.
        """
        try:
            topic.delete()
            logger.info("Deleted topic %s.", topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't delete topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise

    @staticmethod
    def subscribe(topic, protocol, endpoint):
        """
        Subscribes an endpoint to the topic. Some endpoint types, such as email,
        must be confirmed before their subscriptions are active. When a subscription
       is not confirmed, its Amazon Resource Number (ARN) is set to
       'PendingConfirmation'.

        :param topic: The topic to subscribe to.
        :param protocol: The protocol of the endpoint, such as 'sms' or 'email'.
        :param endpoint: The endpoint that receives messages, such as a phone number
                     (in E.164 format) for SMS messages, or an email address for
                     email messages.
        :return: The newly added subscription.
        """
        try:
            subscription = topic.subscribe(
                Protocol=protocol, Endpoint=endpoint, ReturnSubscriptionArn=True)
            logger.info("Subscribed %s %s to topic %s.", protocol, endpoint, topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception(
                "Couldn't subscribe %s %s to topic %s.", protocol, endpoint, topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return subscription

    def list_subscriptions(self, topic=None):
        """
        Lists subscriptions for the current account, optionally limited to a
        specific topic.

        :param topic: When specified, only subscriptions to this topic are returned.
        :return: An iterator that yields the subscriptions.
        """
        try:
            if topic is None:
                subs_iter = self.sns_resource.subscriptions.all()
            else:
                subs_iter = topic.subscriptions.all()
            logger.info("Got subscriptions.")
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get subscriptions.")
            raise
        else:
            return subs_iter

    @staticmethod
    def add_subscription_filter(subscription, attributes):
        """
        Adds a filter policy to a subscription. A filter policy is a key and a
        list of values that are allowed. When a message is published, it must have an
        attribute that passes the filter or it will not be sent to the subscription.

        :param subscription: The subscription the filter policy is attached to.
        :param attributes: A dictionary of key-value pairs that define the filter.
        """
        try:
            att_policy = {key: [value] for key, value in attributes.items()}
            subscription.set_attributes(
                AttributeName='FilterPolicy', AttributeValue=json.dumps(att_policy))
            logger.info("Added filter to subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception(
                "Couldn't add filter to subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
            raise

    @staticmethod
    def delete_subscription(subscription):
        """
        Unsubscribes and deletes a subscription.
        """
        try:
            subscription.delete()
            logger.info("Deleted subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't delete subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
            raise

    def publish_text_message(self, phone_number, message):
        """
        Publishes a text message directly to a phone number without need for a
        subscription.

        :param phone_number: The phone number that receives the message. This must be
                         in E.164 format. For example, a United States phone
                         number might be +12065550101.
        :param message: The message to send.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            response = self.sns_resource.meta.client.publish(
                PhoneNumber=phone_number, Message=message)
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info("Published message to %s.", phone_number)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to %s.", phone_number)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id

    @staticmethod
    def publish_message(topic, message, attributes):
        """
        Publishes a message, with attributes, to a topic. Subscriptions can be filtered
        based on message attributes so that a subscription receives messages only
        when specified attributes are present.

        :param topic: The topic to publish to.
        :param message: The message to publish.
        :param attributes: The key-value attributes to attach to the message. Values
                       must be either `str` or `bytes`.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            att_dict = {}
            for key, value in attributes.items():
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    att_dict[key] = {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': value}
                elif isinstance(value, bytes):
                    att_dict[key] = {'DataType': 'Binary', 'BinaryValue': value}
            response = topic.publish(Message=message, MessageAttributes=att_dict)
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info(
                "Published message with attributes %s to topic %s.", attributes,
                topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id

    @staticmethod
    def publish_multi_message(
            topic, subject, default_message, sms_message, email_message):
        """
        Publishes a multi-format message to a topic. A multi-format message takes
        different forms based on the protocol of the subscriber. For example,
        an SMS subscriber might receive a short, text-only version of the message
        while an email subscriber could receive an HTML version of the message.

        :param topic: The topic to publish to.
        :param subject: The subject of the message.
        :param default_message: The default version of the message. This version is
                            sent to subscribers that have protocols that are not
                            otherwise specified in the structured message.
        :param sms_message: The version of the message sent to SMS subscribers.
        :param email_message: The version of the message sent to email subscribers.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            message = {
                'default': default_message,
                'sms': sms_message,
                'email': email_message
            }
            response = topic.publish(
                Message=json.dumps(message), Subject=subject, MessageStructure='json')
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info("Published multi-format message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id


# -----TEST SNS-----
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
sns = boto3.resource('sns')

sns_wrapper = SnsWrapper(sns)

# Setting up topic attributes
retry_policy = str(json.dumps({
    "http": {
        "defaultHealthyRetryPolicy": {
            "minDelayTarget": 20,
            "maxDelayTarget": 21,
            "numRetries": 3,
            "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
            "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
            "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
            "backoffFunction": "linear"
        },
        "disableSubscriptionOverrides": False
    }
}))
example_access_policy = str(json.dumps({
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "SNS:Publish",
                "SNS:RemovePermission",
                "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:DeleteTopic",
                "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:AddPermission",
                "SNS:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceOwner": "504215336107"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}))
attributes = {
    'DeliveryPolicy': retry_policy,
    'Policy': example_access_policy,
    'KmsMasterKeyId': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:504215336107:key/a0a18770-6a62-418c-b35f-0adee2616270'
}

# Create topic using wrapper
topic = sns_wrapper.create_topic(name='test-sns-functionality', attributes=attributes)
print(topic)

# Lambda ARN (to be subscriber)
lambda_arn = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:504211336307:function:sns-test-lambda'
# Subscribe lambda to created topic
subscriber_arn = sns_wrapper.subscribe(topic, 'lambda', lambda_arn)

# Publish message to topic
sns_wrapper.publish_message(topic, f'This is message from topic: {topic}', attributes={'atr1': 'val1'})
```

---

Possible solutions:
Boto3 docs says:

> if the endpoint and the topic are not in the same Amazon Web Services
> account, the endpoint owner must run the ConfirmSubscription action to
> confirm the subscription

Not sure how to check who is endpoint owner (by that I mean lambda owner), but I have created lambda and SNS topic using the same account.

Does anyone know what am I doing wrong or where the problem is?

Comment: Are you the root user of AWS account you are using for this?

Comment: No, I use IAM user @medium-dimensional

Comment: What is your boto3 script?

Comment: Script: https://www.codepile.net/pile/0kZV5okb
It uses example wrapper class.

Answer (score 0):

### Issue:

The problem was that *sns.amazonaws.com is not authorized to perform: lambda:InvokeFunction*. I am still not 100% sure, if there is any way to set up SNS that invokes Lambda without interfering with lambda itself using boto3.

### My solution:

After setting up **Resource-based policy in Lambda** like this:

```
Statement ID: <name-of-your-policy-statement>
Principal: sns.amazonaws.com
Effect: Allow
Action: lambda:InvokeFunction
Conditions:
{
 "ArnLike": {
  "AWS:SourceArn": "arn:aws:sns:us-east-1:504211136307:test-sns-functionality"
 }
}
```

Lambda triggers were populated automatically with SNS Topic that I chose (AWS:SourceArn - is a SNS Topic arn in this example)

### Additional information:

Logging messages status is really important, but I haven't found any piece of information about setting up topics **Delivery Status Loggings** using boto3. Luckily tried to set attributes used in topic creation methods and it worked!

```
'LambdaSuccessFeedbackRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::504255336111:role/SNS_CloudWatch_Logs_Access_Role',
'LambdaFailureFeedbackRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::504255336111:role/SNS_CloudWatch_Logs_Access_Role'
```

Working script that creates SNS topic (with attributes like logging and policies), subscribes lambda, adds permissions to lambda, publishes message to created topic.

```
import boto3
import json
import logging
from botocore.exceptions import ClientError

logger = logging.getLogger(__name__)
boto3.setup_default_session(profile_name='xxx')


class SnsWrapper:
    """Encapsulates Amazon SNS topic and subscription functions."""

    def __init__(self, sns_resource):
        """
        :param sns_resource: A Boto3 Amazon SNS resource.
        """
        self.sns_resource = sns_resource

    def create_topic(self, name, attributes=None):
        """
        Creates a notification topic.

        :param name: The name of the topic to create.
        :param attributes: Attributes of topic.
        :return: The newly created topic.
        """
        try:
            if attributes:
                topic = self.sns_resource.create_topic(Name=name, Attributes=attributes)
            else:
                topic = self.sns_resource.create_topic(Name=name)
            logger.info("Created topic %s with ARN %s.", name, topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't create topic %s.", name)
            raise
        else:
            return topic

    def list_topics(self):
        """
        Lists topics for the current account.
    
        :return: An iterator that yields the topics.
        """
        try:
            topics_iter = self.sns_resource.topics.all()
            logger.info("Got topics.")
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get topics.")
            raise
        else:
            return topics_iter

    @staticmethod
    def delete_topic(topic):
        """
        Deletes a topic. All subscriptions to the topic are also deleted.
        """
        try:
            topic.delete()
            logger.info("Deleted topic %s.", topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't delete topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise

    @staticmethod
    def subscribe(topic, protocol, endpoint):
        """
        Subscribes an endpoint to the topic. Some endpoint types, such as email,
        must be confirmed before their subscriptions are active. When a subscription
        is not confirmed, its Amazon Resource Number (ARN) is set to
        'PendingConfirmation'.
    
        :param topic: The topic to subscribe to.
        :param protocol: The protocol of the endpoint, such as 'sms' or 'email'.
        :param endpoint: The endpoint that receives messages, such as a phone number
                         (in E.164 format) for SMS messages, or an email address for
                         email messages.
        :return: The newly added subscription.
        """
        try:
            subscription = topic.subscribe(
                Protocol=protocol, Endpoint=endpoint, ReturnSubscriptionArn=True)
            logger.info("Subscribed %s %s to topic %s.", protocol, endpoint, topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception(
                "Couldn't subscribe %s %s to topic %s.", protocol, endpoint, topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return subscription

    def list_subscriptions(self, topic=None):
        """
        Lists subscriptions for the current account, optionally limited to a
        specific topic.
    
        :param topic: When specified, only subscriptions to this topic are returned.
        :return: An iterator that yields the subscriptions.
        """
        try:
            if topic is None:
                subs_iter = self.sns_resource.subscriptions.all()
            else:
                subs_iter = topic.subscriptions.all()
            logger.info("Got subscriptions.")
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't get subscriptions.")
            raise
        else:
            return subs_iter

    @staticmethod
    def add_subscription_filter(subscription, attributes):
        """
        Adds a filter policy to a subscription. A filter policy is a key and a
        list of values that are allowed. When a message is published, it must have an
        attribute that passes the filter or it will not be sent to the subscription.
    
        :param subscription: The subscription the filter policy is attached to.
        :param attributes: A dictionary of key-value pairs that define the filter.
        """
        try:
            att_policy = {key: [value] for key, value in attributes.items()}
            subscription.set_attributes(
                AttributeName='FilterPolicy', AttributeValue=json.dumps(att_policy))
            logger.info("Added filter to subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception(
                "Couldn't add filter to subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
            raise

    @staticmethod
    def delete_subscription(subscription):
        """
        Unsubscribes and deletes a subscription.
        """
        try:
            subscription.delete()
            logger.info("Deleted subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't delete subscription %s.", subscription.arn)
            raise

    def publish_text_message(self, phone_number, message):
        """
        Publishes a text message directly to a phone number without need for a
        subscription.
    
        :param phone_number: The phone number that receives the message. This must be
                             in E.164 format. For example, a United States phone
                             number might be +12065550101.
        :param message: The message to send.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            response = self.sns_resource.meta.client.publish(
                PhoneNumber=phone_number, Message=message)
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info("Published message to %s.", phone_number)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to %s.", phone_number)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id

    @staticmethod
    def publish_message(topic, message, attributes):
        """
        Publishes a message, with attributes, to a topic. Subscriptions can be filtered
        based on message attributes so that a subscription receives messages only
        when specified attributes are present.
    
        :param topic: The topic to publish to.
        :param message: The message to publish.
        :param attributes: The key-value attributes to attach to the message. Values
                           must be either `str` or `bytes`.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            att_dict = {}
            for key, value in attributes.items():
                if isinstance(value, str):
                    att_dict[key] = {'DataType': 'String', 'StringValue': value}
                elif isinstance(value, bytes):
                    att_dict[key] = {'DataType': 'Binary', 'BinaryValue': value}
            response = topic.publish(Message=message, MessageAttributes=att_dict)
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info(
                "Published message with attributes %s to topic %s.", attributes,
                topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id

    @staticmethod
    def publish_multi_message(
            topic, subject, default_message, sms_message, email_message):
        """
        Publishes a multi-format message to a topic. A multi-format message takes
        different forms based on the protocol of the subscriber. For example,
        an SMS subscriber might receive a short, text-only version of the message
        while an email subscriber could receive an HTML version of the message.
    
        :param topic: The topic to publish to.
        :param subject: The subject of the message.
        :param default_message: The default version of the message. This version is
                                sent to subscribers that have protocols that are not
                                otherwise specified in the structured message.
        :param sms_message: The version of the message sent to SMS subscribers.
        :param email_message: The version of the message sent to email subscribers.
        :return: The ID of the message.
        """
        try:
            message = {
                'default': default_message,
                'sms': sms_message,
                'email': email_message
            }
            response = topic.publish(
                Message=json.dumps(message), Subject=subject, MessageStructure='json')
            message_id = response['MessageId']
            logger.info("Published multi-format message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
        except ClientError:
            logger.exception("Couldn't publish message to topic %s.", topic.arn)
            raise
        else:
            return message_id


# -----TEST SNS-----
logging.basicConfig(level=logging.INFO, format='%(levelname)s: %(message)s')
sns = boto3.resource('sns')
lambdas = boto3.client('lambda')

sns_wrapper = SnsWrapper(sns)

# Setting up topic attributes
example_retry_policy = str(json.dumps({
    "http": {
        "defaultHealthyRetryPolicy": {
            "minDelayTarget": 20,
            "maxDelayTarget": 21,
            "numRetries": 3,
            "numMaxDelayRetries": 0,
            "numNoDelayRetries": 0,
            "numMinDelayRetries": 0,
            "backoffFunction": "linear"
        },
        "disableSubscriptionOverrides": False
    }
}))
example_access_policy = str(json.dumps({
    "Version": "2008-10-17",
    "Id": "__default_policy_ID",
    "Statement": [
        {
            "Sid": "__default_statement_ID",
            "Effect": "Allow",
            "Principal": {
                "AWS": "*"
            },
            "Action": [
                "SNS:Publish",
                "SNS:RemovePermission",
                "SNS:SetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:DeleteTopic",
                "SNS:ListSubscriptionsByTopic",
                "SNS:GetTopicAttributes",
                "SNS:AddPermission",
                "SNS:Subscribe"
            ],
            "Resource": "",
            "Condition": {
                "StringEquals": {
                    "AWS:SourceOwner": "504255336111"
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}))
attributes = {
    'DeliveryPolicy': example_retry_policy,
    'Policy': example_access_policy,
    'KmsMasterKeyId': 'arn:aws:kms:us-east-1:504255336111:key/a0a18770-6a62-468c-b35f-0aded2616111',
    'LambdaSuccessFeedbackRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::504255336111:role/SNS_CloudWatch_Logs_Access_Role',
    'LambdaFailureFeedbackRoleArn': 'arn:aws:iam::504255336111:role/SNS_CloudWatch_Logs_Access_Role'
}

# Create topic using wrapper
topic = sns_wrapper.create_topic(name='test-sns-functionality', attributes=attributes)
print(topic)

# Lambda ARN (to be subscriber)
lambda_arn = 'arn:aws:lambda:us-east-1:504255336111:function:sns-test-lambda'
# Subscribe lambda to created topic
subscriber_arn = sns_wrapper.subscribe(topic, 'lambda', lambda_arn)
# Add permissions for SNS to invoke lambda
lambdas.add_permission(
    FunctionName='sns-test-lambda',
    StatementId='permission-for-sns-to-invoke-lambda',
    Principal='sns.amazonaws.com',
    SourceArn=topic.arn,
    Action='lambda:InvokeFunction'
)

# Publish message to topic
sns_wrapper.publish_message(topic, f'This is message from topic: {topic}', attributes={'atr1': 'val1'})
```

Hope someone will find it helpful!